# SwiftUI Picker customization text color soon not work

Tags: swiftui, picker

Using following code I am creating a picker but there is a huge problem with customization.

Only **.background(Color.red)** works.

Why it has be pain with Picker.
It was the same with UIView Picker as well.

I could not find a way to change background or text color.

```
Picker("what is this", selection: $selectedTray) {
                ForEach(trayType, id: \.self) {
                    Text($0)
                        .multilineTextAlignment(.trailing)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.green)
                        .background(Color.blue)
                        
                }
            }.foregroundColor(Color.white)
             .background(Color.red)
```

Comment: Creating my own picker could be faster.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear what customizations you want. In one part you date that only  setting the `.background()` color works, in another you state "I could not find a way to change background or text color." Obviously, you have found out how to change the background color.

```
struct ItemPickerView: View {
    @State private var selectedItem = 1
    let cups: [Int] = Array(1..<21)
    var body: some View {
        Picker("Select Item: ", selection: $selectedItem){
            ForEach(Array(1..<21), id: \.self){ item in
                Text("Item \(item)")
            }
        }
        // Change the Text color with .accentColor()
        .accentColor(.red)
        // As you are aware, set a .background() for the selection background
        .background(Color.yellow)
    }
}
```

If this is not what you want, please post an image or a very good description of what you do want.

Comment: What about the segment text and background colors ?

Answer (score 0):

Inside a `Form`
You need to apply the `listRowBackground` to set the background color

```
Form {
    Picker(selection: $selection, content: {
        ForEach(items) { item in
            Text(item.title)
                .tag(item.id)
        }
    })
    .pickerStyle(.inline)
    .listRowBackground(Color.black) <-- Here
}
```